# Swift Leak even when unowned is used with Protocol in small code example

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code:
I have the `ViewWithCollectionView` on my story board. It's just a simple empty view created for this example.

I have set my `delegate` as unowned, but Xcode Leaks still show this as a leak, and I do not understand why. Can someone help please?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController  {
    @IBOutlet weak var theView: ViewWithCollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

class ViewWithCollectionView: UICollectionView, SomeProtocol {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        collectionViewLayout = SomeLayout(with: self)
    }
}

open class SomeLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, SomeProtocol {
    unowned var delegate: SomeProtocol

    init(with delegate: SomeProtocol) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init()
    }
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

protocol SomeProtocol: class {}
```

here is the image of the Leak: Xcode 8, Swift 3
[image]

**Here is the link to the code with on GitHub so you can see it -> [Github Link](https://github.com/patchthecode/leakTest)**

Comment: I cannot see a leak here. Could you elaborate your example a little more  - where are the instances created etc.? Please sikp everything not needed here (like ViewController class ?)

Comment: The usual practice here would be to make your delegate 'weak' instead of 'unowned'.

Comment: What makes you think there's a leak here?

Comment: I have added the image of the leak. I have also added a Github url with the code

Comment: Try to define the outlet as `weak`

Comment: @LucaD'Alberti i just now did. It still has the leak

Comment: The project link no longer exists. Is this still happening in Xcode 11.1?

Comment: @CyberMew even thought the project link is gone, the entire project code is pasted above.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the project from your GIT repo and ran the project and it had a leak like you mentioned. The leak was fixed once I changed

```
unowned var delegate: SomeProtocol
```

to

```
weak var delegate: SomeProtocol?
```

Also there was no leak when I just declared it without `unowned`.

```
var delegate: SomeProtocol?
```

Comment: This is very strange. Neither `weak` nor `unowned` should increase the reference count and therefore behave the same.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen yea im starting to thing this is an AppleBug

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe there is no memory leak at all...

I just modified the project a little:

- Create a new ViewController with a button,
- Embed it into a Navigation Controller
- Set this as the initial view controller
- Link the button to push the original ViewController onto the stack
- Add deinitializers with print statements in all the classes of the original post

Now, when I profile this, I definetly see the memory leak after pressing the button to push the original `ViewController`. But when I hit the back button, I also see the deinitializers being called:

```
ViewController.deinit

ViewWithCollectionView.deinit
SomeLayout.deinit
<End of Run>
```

Strange, isn't it?

Comment: ok.. now i am officially confused. Unless Xcode leak finder is buggy? :/